Why is the compton continuum so uniform?
According to the Klein-Nishina model, a photon that undergoes compton scattering will scatter at different angles preferentially according to its energy, shown in the image below.

Then, looking at the formula for the energy of a compton scattered photon:

This would mean that of the incident photon, a large majority of the resulting scattered photons would have a typical energy. Taking a photon of 2MeV, it will mostly result in photons scattered at a very low angle. These resulting photons will thus have a higher chance to have a high energy (low scattering angle) than a low energy (high scattering angle). Looking next at a classic energy spectrum where a Compton background is visible:

It looks pretty uniform. I would expect there to be more resulting photons of high energy escaping the detector. And thus the Compton background to be higher in the low energies than the high energies (as high energies are lost resulting in low energies being deposited in the detector).

with out knowing what the detector is, we can't really add anything. Now the ordinate is labeled as a "counts" density, so it's probably raw data not corrected for detector efficieny. If you look at the coefficient of variation for each channel ($c_i = \sigma_i/y_i = f_i/\sqrt{y_i}$) and $f_i$ is function of energy ($i$), then a correction has been applied.

@JEB Oh, I didn't notice. Either way a classic photon peak spectrum, from what I know, shows the Compton background as being pretty uniform, this is just an image I found online to show what I mean. Maybe the photons I am talking about might be low energy making the Klein-Nishina model be closer to uniform probability for all angles (and thus energies) for scattered photons.

note that the histogram has GeV level energies on the abscissa, while the Klein-Nishina is MeV scale. One question: is the cross section done in lab angle or CoM? I would suspect lab, since it's forward peaked...

@JEB I have no idea what lab angle or CoM is. The histogram is kev scale, and the peak is at around 2.3 MeV, so according to the Klein-Nishina model the scattering angle should predominantly be forward.

Comments got too long, so here's my answer:
The Klein-Nishina formula has to be Lab angle, since defining a center-of-mass frame isn't fruitful: is it defined by the incident gamma and the atomic electron, or the atom, or what? So, that comment was extraneous. I have no idea what @JEB was thinking.
As pointed out, the histogram is at vastly higher energies (3 orders of magnitude) than the KN polar plot, but it's safe to assume it's strongly forward-peaked.
Here's the problem: we don't know what the incident gamma energy is, nor do we know the detector set-up.
It could be a fixed angle detector, which sees a Compton peak, and then a tail due to radiative corrections. This is certainly the case with elastic $p(e, e')p$ scattering.
In that, there is an elastic peak plus internal (virtual) and external (real, in part of the experimental apparatus) corrections due to Bremsstrahlung...i.e, an incident electron emits a virtual/real photon, and then elastically scatters with higher probability at lower energy, and scattering into your detector. Or: it scatters elastically at the correct energy and then brems a photon, losing energy before detection.
There is much formalism to deal with this, that all falls under the name "Radiative Corrections" (RC).
Now I don't know much about RC in Compton scattering, but there are papers, e.g. Brown and Feynman (1951): https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.85.231
The other option, which is how you have interpreted it in the question, is that the detector is "large acceptance", it sees many angles, and the energy is directly related to the scattering angle via the famous Compton formula (which I will show you how to do in MathJax, which will produce the same image as the LaTex clip you have in the question):
$$ E_{\gamma'} =
\frac{E_{\gamma}}
{1 + (E_{\gamma}/m_ec^2)(1-\cos\theta)}
$$
I think (but don't know) that this case is not likely, rendering the question moot.
